# How to delete MDB file after using UpdateCursor?

Tags: arcpy

I am updating MDB file with update cursor after updating complete I want change the file extension MDB to other. It shows it's in use by another process. Find below code.

```
arcpy.env.workspace=ConvertedMdbFile 
Styletablelist=arcpy.ListTables("","")
for table in Styletablelist:
    if str(table)=='Fill Symbols' or  str(table)=='Line Symbols' or str(table)=='Marker Symbols':
       with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table,["Name","Category"]) as Tablecursor:
          for row in Tablecursor:
             namelist=row[0].split(".sde.")             
             if str(row[1])=="Layer" and len(namelist)==1:
                 styleName=row[0]                                

                 row[0]=prefixname+styleName
                 Tablecursor.updateRow(row)                                
del Tablecursor
del table 
del Styletablelist
OriginalMDBFile=str(os.path.splitext(INPUTMDBFILE)[0])
os.rename(ConvertedMdbFile , OriginalMDBFile+ '.style')
```

In above `os.rename` through error

> [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Look at the actual lock files to see what is interfering; It's more likely a session in the background than the cursor.

Comment: The funny thing is that your code worked for me. However I've got a few concerns: are you using your script as standalone script or within ArcMap? If the latter then lock is from software itself. Locks in ArcMap are source of a lot of trouble and aren't always released in predictable way. Try to add time.sleep(x) line before renaming, where x is time in seconds. Sometimes lock is not released immediately. Also note that judging by the way OriginalMDBFile var is created, your mdb will be moved to current Python working directory, I'm not sure if you want it.